# Iris Colour Picker: option to show an input to enter colour value

Tags: javascript

Is there an option in the [Iris colour picker](http://automattic.github.io/Iris/) that shows an input? Ie, it allows a user to enter a hexadecimal colour value into the input or select a colour using the colour gradient.

I need to allow both selection of colour through a picker and to enter the colour value. So I am hoping Iris has an option for this. I have looked through the documentation but there is no mention of this.

Comment: Click on the link you provided and go to [Usage](http://automattic.github.io/Iris/#usage). There is an `<input>` where iris is attached to. What stops the user from using this input?

Comment: @Clijsters yes I read the documentation as stated in my post. I would like to know if there is an option, for eg, `$('foo').iris({showInput: true});` that when the Iris colour picker popup is displayed there is also an input in there for the user to enter a colour. I have a button that users click not an input so there's no input for us.